# $_SESSION recuperar datos

Tags: php, pdo, session

Tengo un archivo que recupera las ID y hace un login por roles tal que así:

**validar.php**:

```
<?php
//Fichero que usara para mandar los datos recibidos más abajo para pasarlos por el controlador.
include '../controlador/usuariosControlador.php';
//Recoge los datos de index.php introducidos en el login, verifica que en ambos campos existan datos.
if (isset($_POST['usuario']) || isset($_POST['pass'])) {
    if (trim($_POST['usuario']) == '' || trim($_POST['pass']) == '') {
        echo 'false';
    } else {
        $usuariosCon = new usuariosControlador();
        $usuario     = $usuariosCon->validar($_POST['usuario'], $_POST['pass']);
        if (count($usuario) > 0) {
            //Una vez detecta que el usuario existe le indicaremos los datos que debe seguir la SESSION para calificar los roles, es decir, hacia donde debe de dirigir todo el tráfico del log según su rol.
            session_start();
            $_SESSION['id']         = $usuario['id'];
            $_SESSION['usuario']    = $usuario['usuario'];
            $_SESSION['privilegio'] = $usuario['privilegio'];
            echo 'true';
            echo $validacion;
            if ($_SESSION['privilegio'] == 0) {
                header('location: userinv.php');
            } elseif ($_SESSION['privilegio'] == 1) {
                header('location: user.php');
            } elseif ($_SESSION['privilegio'] == 2) {
                header('location: jefe.php');
            } elseif ($_SESSION['privilegio'] == 3) {
                header('location: administrador.php');
            } elseif ($_SESSION['privilegio'] == 4) {
                header('location: superadmin.php');
            } else {
                echo 'false';
            }
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Como vemos redirige a las webs que yo le digo, y dentro de esta tiene opciones para moverse.

Bien pues si entra a una de estas entra así:

**Menuadmin.php**:

```
session_start();
//Iniciaremos la variable SESSION y con ello le indicaremos QUIÉN NO tiene permisos para acceder aquí
 if (!isset($_SESSION["privilegio"]) || $_SESSION["privilegio"] == 0) {
print "<script>alert(\"Acceso invalido!\");window.location='../../index.php';</script>";
}

if (!isset($_SESSION["privilegio"]) || $_SESSION["privilegio"] == 1) {
print "<script>alert(\"Acceso invalido!\");window.location='../../index.php';</script>";
}

if (!isset($_SESSION["privilegio"]) || $_SESSION["privilegio"] == 2) {
print "<script>alert(\"Acceso invalido!\");window.location='../../index.php';</script>";
}
```

Para comprobar que tiene permisos deja acceder o no. Bien una vez que accede este quiere dirigirse a su menú principal pero no puedo, ya que los datos de su sesión es como si ya los hubiera perdido.

Por ejemplo yo le digo vuelve al archivo **validar.php** para que lo redirija a su index predefinido pero la página se queda en blanco:

```
<?php echo '<a href="../../validar.php">Menu</a>'; ?></li>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cuando estas regresando a **Validar.php** compruebas los datos POST que son nulos cuando regresas al pulsar el link Menu, agrega un **else** para que compruebe en caso de los datos Post ser nulos si hay datos de sesion.
Te dejo un ejemplo de lo que me refiero:

```
<?php
//Fichero que usara para mandar los datos recibidos más abajo para pasarlos por el controlador.
include "../controlador/usuariosControlador.php";
//inicia la sesion
session_start();
//Recoge los datos de index.php introducidos en el login, verifica que en ambos campos existan datos.
if (isset($_POST["usuario"]) || isset($_POST["pass"])) {
if (trim($_POST["usuario"]) == "" || trim($_POST["pass"]) == "") {
    echo "false";
} else {
    // comprobar y asignalos datos de sesion
    $usuariosCon = new usuariosControlador();
    $usuario = $usuariosCon->validar($_POST["usuario"], $_POST["pass"]);
    if (count($usuario) > 0) {
        $_SESSION["id"] = $usuario["id"];
        $_SESSION["usuario"] = $usuario["usuario"];
        $_SESSION["privilegio"] = $usuario["privilegio"];
        echo "true";
        echo $validacion;
        //comprueba los privilegios del usuario
        PrivilegioUsuario();
    }
}
}else if(isset($_SESSION["id"], $_SESSION["usuario"], $_SESSION["privilegio"])){
    //este else se ejecuta si no hay datos POST, comprueba que haya datos de sesion y en caso de haberlas, comprueba los privilegios del usuario
    PrivilegioUsuario();
}

//una funcion para evitar repetir el mismo codigo y llamarlo desde dos sitios
function PrivilegioUsuario(){
//Una vez detecta que el usuario existe le indicaremos los datos que debe seguri la SESSION para calificar los roles, es decir, hacia donde debe de dirigir todo el trafigo del log segun su rol.

        if ($_SESSION['privilegio'] == 0) {
            header('location: userinv.php');
        } else if ($_SESSION['privilegio'] == 1) {
            header('location: user.php');
        } else if ($_SESSION['privilegio'] == 2) {
            header('location: jefe.php');
        } else if ($_SESSION['privilegio'] == 3) {
            header('location: administrador.php');
        } else if ($_SESSION['privilegio'] == 4){
            header('location: superadmin.php');
        } 
        else {
            echo "false";
        }

}
?>
```

Comment: me lanza este error: Notice: Undefined index: id in C:\xampp\htdocs\deimos\vista\validar.php on line 15
true
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Using $this when not in object context in C:\xampp\htdocs\deimos\vista\validar.php:20 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\deimos\vista\validar.php on line 20

Comment: Disculpa fallo mio, no hay que colocar el "$this->" edito el codigo

Comment: vale funcionar ahora funciona de la siguiente manera, si entra al sitio web con las credenciales, pero cuanod pulso el boton menu que linka con validar.php sigue dejando la página en blanco, lo cual me deja a cuadros por que no podemos ver donde reside el error.

Comment: Si has echo "copy paste" de mi codigo deberia funcionar, ¿podria venirte ahora el problema de la configuracion de xampp? Si te deja en blanco aun, es que ni se pasan parametros POST ni hay datos de sesion. Has probado en algun hosting que no sea localhost ?

Comment: crea un archivo php de prueba, con este codigo de ejemplo: **<?php
session_start();
if (isset($_SESSION["test"])) {
 echo "Si Hay Sesion: " . $_SESSION["test"];
} else {
    $_SESSION["test"] = "prueba";
 echo "No hay sesion, se ha creado una, recarga la pagina para probar";
}
?>**
ejecutalo y la primera vez deberia decirte que no hay sesion, tras recargar la web ya deberia darte el mensaje de que si hay sesion si todo esta correcto.

Comment: Exacto me dice que existe sesión una vez recargo, en resumen, no la tiene, recargo y si la tiene, acabo de hacer esa prueba con el archivo PHP de validar recargando la pagina pero no ha funcionado xD!

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/59124/discussion-between-israel-and-alberto-cepero-de-andres).

Answer (score 0):

Buenas, revisa la documentación de `session` para que veas como funciona.

http://php.net/manual/es/function.session-start.php

Ademas, ten en cuenta que en tu código, si vuelvo a "validar.php" sin valores en POST (como haces en el `<?php echo '<a href="../../validar.php">Menu</a>'; ?></li>` siempre te va a dar false, porque tú mismo obligas a que exista un `POST['usuario']` y `POST['pass']`

Comentas que la página se queda en blanco, ¿has revisado con click derecho "Ver código fuente de la página" que realmente esté en blanco? Puede que estés imprimiendo el `echo "false";`.

¿El error log te da algún error? ¿Podemos ver el controlador?

Comment: En el código fuente de la página no imprime nada tampoco, como se queda en blanco la de validar supongo.